# render value box from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to develop an application in shiny, where i am plotting a graph using ggplot.

my graph is in the form of stacked column chart. It has categories filled (yes,No).

I wanted to render the value of yes and No in my dashboard with the Value box.

Could anyone suggest me how i could do it.

I have the server code for generating the plot. I just need to know, how i can generate the value from the chart.

Any lead with sample example would be helpful.

Below is the server code

```
output$mat <- renderPlot({
   data <- cl_count <- cl %>%
     filter(year(Date)> 2016 & year(Date)<2018)%>%
     group_by(Date, Code, Accepted) %>%
     summarise(count=n())


   ggplot(cl_count, aes(Date, count, fill=Accepted))+
     geom_bar(stat='identity')
 })
```

EDIT:

```
cl <- data.frame(c(30.01.2017, 31.12.2017,2.01.2017,04.02.2016), c(Yes,No,Yes,No), c(2345, 3456, 54637))
```

The above is the sample data.

I have obtained the bar chart with the year along x-axis and the count value of accpetance(Yes and No) along the Y axis.

With the above code, I am able to render a plot . I would like to have a infoboxoutput, with a value box, that can tell the count value of Yes and No from the graph. With the change in graph, the count should change.

Comment: Are you stuck with making your plot, or retrieving the value? As in, are you having a Shiny problem or a ggplot problem? It will be easier for people to help if you `dput` your data here

Comment: @camille the problem is , I am able to display the plot, but i would like to create a value box from the plot.

Comment: That data doesn't seem like it's what you're working with, though. No column headings; dates are formatted as numbers with multiple decimal places in them, not as dates; strings need to be in quotation marks; third column is one value short of the others. Your `count` operation will just give a count of 2 for each--is that what you're going for?

Comment: @camille Those are not the exact data I am working with . I showed yuóu the sample how it is with some modification . The Plot I am displaying is perfect . It satisfies my needs. The point is , from the plot , I want the numeric count of YEs and No. How shoul i do it? Could you provide me with an example